# Connection failed with racer reasoner

Tags: java, description-logic

I'm trying to use racer (Description Logic reasoner), but i get the following error

```
com.racersystems.jracer.RacerClientException: Connection refused: connect
at com.racersystems.jracer.RacerClient.openConnection(RacerClient.java:76)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

the code i'm executing is the following :

```
package test;
import com.racersystems.jracer.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 8088;
    String filename="\"/jracer-2-0.zip_expanded/jracer-2-0/demo/people+pets.owl\"";
    RacerClient racer = new RacerClient(ip,port);
    try {
         racer.openConnection();
         System.out.println(racer.sendRaw("(owl-read-file " + filename + ")"));
         System.out.println(racer.sendRaw("(all-atomic-concepts)"));
         racer.closeConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I don't know who to solve it ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently trying to connect to a service that is running on the same machine as you are running the program ... using the `127.0.0.1` loopback interface.

The fact that it is giving you a "connection refused" response means that the service is not currently running on "this machine" or the port that you have specified.

The solution will be to ensure that the service is running and listening on the specified IP and port; e.g. check the IP address and port, and start or restart the service.

Comment: the port number was wrong thank you